# Assigning callback events from an array of strings (PIXI.js)

Tags: javascript, typescript, callback, pixi.js

all. I have kind of a doozy of a problem, that could be solved really simply, if I just wanted to duplicate the code. I mean, really, it's a small part of a project that I'm doing just to see if I *can*, more than anything else, but it *is* bothering me since I've thought it up.

### The Project

*For fun*, I've decided to take someone's ActionScript 3, text-based game engine and convert it to TypeScript and ultimately JavaScript using PixiJS.
The thing is, there are still 20213 errors to be fixed running `tsc`, so I could just leave this to a later date. But I was working on the Button class, which they defined as a subclass of MovieClip. That's fine; I just responded by reading up on PIXI buttons, and they seem fairly straightforward. Just, in the button's constructor, add something akin to the following lines:

```
export class Button extends PIXI.Sprite {
    private _callback : Function;
    private _height : number;
    private _width : number;
    public get callback() : Function { return this._callback; }
    public set callback(fn : Function) {this._callback = fn; }
    public get height() : number { return this._height; }
    public set height(h : number) {this._height = h; }
    public get width() : number {return this._width; }
    public set width(w : number) {this._width = w; }
    public constructor(width = 180, height = 90, callback: Function = null){
        super(new PIXI.Texture(new PIXI.BaseTexture(GLOBAL.BTN_BACK, PIXI.SCALE_MODES.NEAREST)));
        this.callback = callback;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.buttonMode = true;
        this.interactive = true;
        this.anchor.set(0.5);
        this.on('mousedown', this.callback)
            .on('touchstart', this.callback);
    }
}
```

That's a bit of a simplified version, and the version I did on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/NRmLZg?editors=0011) uses a `Container` and a private `_sprite` field instead (as well as a ColorMatrixFilter that doesn't work too well on the black icons I picked out, but that's not really important for this question), but that's roughly the gist of how it's done.

### The Problem

The problem is that, in the codepen, I'd like to do the following:

```
// assign `this.callback` to each of the following events:
let that = this;
['click','mousedown','touchstart'].map(evt => that.on(evt, that.callback});
```

with a simple call being passed in their constructors elsewhere:

```
for (let n = 0; n < 5; ++n){
    btnArray.push(new Button(16, 16, () => console.info('You pushed button %d', n)));
}
```

but I'm not getting anything from them, even in the Chrome Console. I even logged that ColorMatrixFilter I mentioned earlier, to see if it was `console.info` that was wrong. Nope. So now, I'm confused on that. I was hoping to be able to just make a `GLOBAL` (a legacy static object from the AS source) key to iterate through for the events, but it looks like that's not happening.

### The Questions

1. Is what I'm trying to do feasible, if odd? Is it blocked by a security feature (for which I'd be grateful)? If not, what am I doing wrong?
2. Should I even *worry* about setting all these different event handlers, or is just listening to `click` enough?

Comment: Any particular reason you need to use an arrow function to do this?  While you're using `that` to retain `this`, any references to `this` inside `that.on` will still refer to `this`, not `that`.  Try replacing with `['click','mousedown','touchstart'].map(function(evt) { that.on(evt, that.callback} } );`

Comment: That worked! Thank you. Could you make that an official answer so I can give you the proper points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an arrow function like your event map is executed the `this` context is not set, so any code that references `this` is going to get the current value, including any functions your map calls.

Replace your event map with the following:

```
['click','mousedown','touchstart'].map(function(evt) { that.on(evt, that.callback} } );
```

A demonstration:

```js
function Named(x) {
    this.name = x;
}
var foo = new Named("foo");
var bar = new Named("bar");

var showFunc = function show() {
    // this is context dependant
    console.log(this.name);
}

var showArrow;
// this is the window
showArrow = () => console.log(this.name);

var fooShowArrow;
(function() {
    // this is foo
    that = this;
    fooShowArrow = () => console.log(that.name);
}).apply(foo);

var example = function(func) {
    // For the demo, at this point, this will always be bar
    func.apply(this, [ "arbitrary value" ]);
}

// explicitly set the current "this" to bar for the execution of these functions
example.apply(bar, [showFunc]);  // works
example.apply(bar, [showArrow]);  // fails, this is still the window
example.apply(bar, [fooShowArrow]);   // fails, this is still foo
```